# Root Partition not of the size of EBS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I created one **OEL 6.6 Ec2 on AWS** in one of the Region.

And assigned

```
Root Partition 25GB (When first seen it was hinting 15G)
And other EBS for other purpose
```

When I did `lsblk` on it I found that

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  25G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  15G  0 part /
```

While I created one of the Amazon's preferred AMI like : Amazon Linux Image or Centos provided Community AMI's I found :

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  25G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  25G  0 part /
```

Can anyone please explain me what is wrong here. Are these Logical partitioning done by the AMI vendor's at the time of creation or is something wrong with my configurations on AWS itself? How can I overcome this as I need that AMI only?

Answer (score 0):

As @DusanBajic Suggested in :[StackOverflow : Root Partition not of the size of EBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606990/root-partition-not-of-the-size-of-ebs)

To overcome the same, You need to install that following module via these steps :

```
wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/epel/6/x86_64/cloud-utils-growpart-0.27-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/epel/6/x86_64/dracut-modules-growroot-0.20-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh cloud-utils-growpart-0.27-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh dracut-modules-growroot-0.20-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -qa kernel | sed 's/^kernel-//'  | xargs -I {} dracut -f /boot/initramfs-{}.img {}
growpart /dev/xvda 1
init 6 or Restart using Amazon's own console
```